# Writing Parallelly into two files python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am just trying to write parallelly in to two file with the help of threading.

```
def dmesg (i):

    cmd = 'dmesg'
    print cmd
    (status, cmd_out) = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    fil = open('dmesg_logs', 'w')
    fil.write(cmd_out)
    fil.close()

def dump (i):

    cmd = 'lsmod'
    print cmd
    (status, cmd_out) = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    fil = open('logs', 'w')
    fil.write(cmd_out)
    fil.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":

    t1 = threading.Thread(target = dmesg, args=(0,))
    t1.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = dump, args=(0,))
    t2.start()
    while True : 
        "My own code"
```

Here my problem is logs file is not created in thread 2. Can i iknow what am doing wrong ?

Comment: I replaced your commands with `ls` and `date` and it worked perfectly.  Can you try that?  Also please note that you are using `commands` when you should probably use `subprocess` instead.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Some suggest like for i/o operations, we have to go for threading and for cpu bound operation, we have to go for subprocess.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I never said anything about using or not using threading.  I said don't use `commands`.  It's deprecated.

Comment: @JohnZwinck date and ls works fine. But not with my commands.

Comment: Try using `subprocess` as suggested, and capture the `stderr`. Maybe something is failing and you're not catching it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Am getting same results in subprocess also

Comment: @taz: What if you swap the two commands?  Or run just the failing one by itself?  Try more combinations and let us know what you find.

Comment: @john Zwinck if one command it works fine. If i run two it fails.

Comment: @taz: What if you swap which command runs in which function/thread?  Which one fails then?

Comment: @JohnZwinck sorry for inconvinence, i made a small mistake which is rectified now. Now if i give any commands which is related to realtime log capturing it does not works !. Eg am using hcidump which will capture all bt related logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmd = ['dmesg']
with open ('dmesg_log.txt', 'w') as out1:
    retun1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout=out1)
```

Found the solution. Above code works for me.